# Parse javascript for loop, creating multiple objects without duplicates

Tags: javascript, node.js, parse-platform

I am having trouble with Parse in Javascript. I am just trying to loop through my list of objects that I have in an array. If the imageURL matches one in Parse, then do nothing. If their is no imageURL from the array, in Parse, then add the row to Parse.

I think my issue is synchronicity. Its is currently saving the same row (same name, imageURL, and fbURL) many times to Parse. Basically saving one row, and its duplicated 70 times.

```
 for (var i = 0; i < listobjects.length; i++) {

      objName = listobjects[i]["name"]
      objImageURL = listobjects[i]["imageURL"]
      objfbURL = listobjects[i]["fbURL"]

      console.log("NAME: " + listobjects[i]["name"])

      // Check if record is in Parse
      var query = new Parse.Query(Recipe);
      query.equalTo("imageURL", listobjects[i]["imageURL"]);
      query.find({
        success: function(results) {
          if (results.length > 0) {
            // Do nothing. We have a result. Or maybe check if videoURL is present
            console.log("Object is already in DB.")
          } else {


            // Save the new object.
            var recipeObject = new Recipe();
            recipeObject.save({name: objName, imageURL:objImageURL, fbURL: objfbURL}, {
              success: function(object) {
                console.log("Object Saved!")
              },
              error: function(model, error) {
                console.log("Error saving object!")
              }
            });


          }
        },
        error: function(error) {
          alert("Error: " + error.code + " " + error.message);
        }
      });

    }
```

Comment: You've not given enough here to reproduce the issue.

Answer (score 1):

Change

```
for (var i = 0; i < listobjects.length; i++) {
  objName = listobjects[i]["name"]
  // ...
}
```

to

```
listobjects.forEach(function(obj) {
  // access obj.name, obj.imageURL
  // ...
});
```

to create a scope and the right object will be used within the find callback.